# Sql count distinct values based on column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need an help about a sql query. I have a table as the following

```
error   session
error1     1 
error1     1
error2     1
error1     2
error1     2
error2     2
```

I have to count errors once related to session. The result should be

```
error   number of errors     
error1         2
error2         2
```

Thank you

Comment: [Edit] your question and provide sample data and expected results for that data. This question probably has many duplicates, but it's difficult to be sure because your question is so unclear.

Answer (score 4):

Use aggregated function `count` and `group by` to do this.

Try this:-

```
Select error, count(distinct session) as number_of_errors
from
your_table_name
group by error
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to `group by` the error and count the distinct `sessions`, and you can do that pretty much repeating these words in a query

```
select  error, count(distinct session)
from    yourTable
group by error
```